# Change background color of a cell from a custom formula

Tags: vba, excel

I have created formula function which looks like this

```
Function CalculateCPOTracker(Model As String, Mcodes As String, Opt As String, RegionId As String, RecTotalAvailNFormat As String, RecTotalAvailValue As String, GroupModel As String, MandateFormat As String, MandateValue As String, RowNumber As String) As Double
.....
CalculateCPOTracker = buffer

End Function
```

In the end of this function I need to change background color of a cell. I have tried to do something like this

```
Worksheets("Rec").Range("BA:BA").Rows(38).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
```

But it does not work for me. It stops calculate properly.
Is that possible to do this from the formula function?

Comment: No, A function called from a worksheet can not directly change the properties of a cell.

Comment: Thanks. It saves a lot of time for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
Worksheets("Rec").cells(52,38).interior.color = rgb(255,255,0)
```

But changing font from a function is not a good practice in VBA. Ususally functions should return value, and changes should be done by a sub. Like this:

```
Public sub ChangeColor (rngCell as range)
    rngCell.interior.color = rgb(255,255,0)
end sub
```

Even with optional values for the colors:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ChangeColor(rngCell As Range, _
                        Optional lngR As Long = 255, _
                        Optional lngG As Long = 255, _
                        Optional lngB As Long = 0)

    rngCell.Interior.Color = RGB(lngR, lngG, lngB)

End Sub
```

Edit:
Actually, it depends on what you are trying to do:
If you want to use the function as a worksheet function, you cannot change the color, as @Scott Craner has mentioned in the comments. But, if you run the function from VBA, you can do it. Try this small example to see the difference:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function ColorAndBy10(rngMyRange As Range) As Long

    rngMyRange.Interior.Color = vbRed
    ColorAndBy10 = 10 * rngMyRange.Value

End Function


Public Sub TestMe()

    Range("b1").Formula = "=ColorAndBy10(A1)"
    Range("b2") = ColorAndBy10(Range("a2"))

End Sub


Public Sub TestMe()

    Range("b1").Formula = "=ColorAndBy10(A1)"
    Range("b2") = ColorAndBy10(Range("a2"))

End Sub
```

Comment: It creates a circular reference and that is why it is not working for me as well as my approach. I am not sure that it is possible to change cell color like I want. Because I am changing the same cell in which I make calculation.

Comment: So according to your example and also @Scott Craner comment unfortunately I cannot do this. Thanks a lot for your reply.

Comment: Welcome. It really seems impossible to change the font color through a worksheet formula.